# Play notification on fixed device

Tags: windows-10, audio

My headset is constantly plugged into my Windows 10 laptop, but I often miss Outlook's e-mail reminders. Is there a way to make the reminder sound to (also) play on my laptop's speakers, even though a headset is plugged in. Of course, all other sounds (calls, videos) should still be played on the headset only.

Comment: If your laptop's soundcard has an option to split its outputs (most Realteks has) then you could configure to use a different output for a different application.